# Unable to access xml file under war folder

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I am unable to access any xml file under war folder from broswer.

i tried in all possible browsers.

Is there any settings do we need to concentrate.
Thanks,

Comment: Is it directly in /war, or in one of subfolders?

Comment: directly in war (/war/test.xml).

Comment: And what is the error code when you try to access it?

Comment: when i tried to access using "http://localhost:8888/test.xml" i am getting 404. the request is not even reaching server

Comment: Did the Server start up correctly or were there errors in the startup? Are you able to access any other file or servlet ?

Comment: I am able to access other file like html,jsp under war.
and no errors in the startup

Comment: The server started up properly and am able to access other filetypes under war